# Iterate over files in a directory with Python - code not working

Tags: python, loops, csv, for-loop, directory

The following code works one one specified file:

```
sec_urls = []
filename = './index/2000Q1.csv'

with open(filename, newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
        url = line[4].strip()
        sec_urls.append(url)
        print(url, 'downloaded and added to list')
```

I would like to perform this on several files contained within the directory INDEX_DIR, however I am not getting any results with the following code:

```
sec_urls = []

for filename in os.listdir(INDEX_DIR):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        with open(filename, newline='') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            for line in reader:
                url = line[4].strip()
                sec_urls.append(url)
                print(url, 'downloaded and added to list')
```

I am not receiving any error messages, I am just not receiving an output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated (I am an absolute beginner).

Comment: You are opening the file `filename`, which is only the name of the file and does not include the path. Try: `with open(os.path.join(INDEX_DIR, filename), newline='') as csvfile:`

Comment: @Johannes Thanks for the reply, though this hasn't changed the outcome

Comment: @Johannes Actually, I don't think that this is the issue (or rather I think that your solution will work once I have fixed the actual issue). I think I have a path issue as I have just discovered an empty `INDEX_DIR` folder mixed up in the path with the actual folder I want.